# Interpretation of R glm output p value, specifically one-tail vs two-tail?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, interpretation

I'm nervous this has been asked elsewhere (feel free to point me there) but I had trouble finding it.

My question is:   I am doing a logistic regression to examine whether the length of time between two surgeries led to more complications in the second surgery.  I'm doing this analysis in R. Going in, I very much think that if there is less time between surgeries (the "TimeFrame" variable.  Its # of days.
I especially think if there's a very short amount of time, in my head I would think under 90 days would be important) that there would be more complications (variable is yes/no).  When I do the regression, my output looks like this:

[image]

When I was reading [here](http://users.stat.umn.edu/%7Egeyer/classes/3011/rweb/rsimp.html) and in Joseph M. Hilbe's book "Practical Guide to Logistic Regression", it said that what you see is the p value for a two-tailed test, and if you're interested in a one-tailed test you'd divide that p-value by 2.

Hence, my question:   I THINK I am interested in a one-tailed test, given I think its shorter time frames that lead to complications, not longer. And given I think there'll be more complications, not less. Is that a safe assumption?  If so, I'd divide that 0.0958 by 2 and get 0.0479, which would then be significant correct?  Do I need to divide anything else?

As an aside, my data has "Timeframes" from 1 day to 800 days.  As I mentioned I think the very short timeframes would be more important to this question than the difference between 500 and 600 days.  Is there a different way you'd recommend analyzing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so you think shorter time frames lead to higher risk of the outcome.  That is equivalent to the alternative hypothesis

$$ H_A : \beta<0 $$

You can do the one tailed test directly since you're given the z value. In R...

```r
pnorm(-1.665)
>>>[1] 0.04795638
```

Your result would be marginally significant given the 0.05 threshold (yay, I guess you can publish).

> I THINK I am interested in a one-tailed test, given I think its shorter time frames that lead to complications, not longer. And given I think there'll be more complications, not less. Is that a safe assumption?

We can't comment on appropriateness of assumptions without some more background on the design and the study.

Comment: The p-value from `pnorm(-1.665)` is of course exactly half the two-sided p-value given in the glm output table, the same as that posited by OP.